# How to integrate with FactorSoft/Cadence?

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

I am currently have a MERN/PERN stack application and am trying to integrate into FactorSoft. I am using amqp/rabbitmq for mq and axios on both the front end and server side to do requests. Does FactorSoft have exposed api endpoints to hit, and if so, what are the parameters for them?

Some of the objects I would need to sync would be along the lines of
`account:  { id:string, accountNumber:string, name:string, etc... } document: { id:string, type:string, file:blob, etc... } invoice: { id:string, invoiceNumber:string, account:fk, totalAmount:calculated, currency: fk, etc... } invoice line: { id: string, invoiceId: fk, amount: numeric,  etc... }`

Contacted JackHenry, they pointed me here to ask about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.